# Nodejs login system password is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication

I'm building a login system with Nodejs, Express and MongoDB. When I clicked the login button I kept getting redirected to the "You are not verified" page. I decided to console log the passwords to see what was going on and the password the user inputted as well as the password stored in the database are coming up as undefined(undefined at the point of the console.logs) for some reason. How can I fix this?

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  //Get user fields
  const userEmail = req.body.loginEmail;
  const userPass = req.body.userPass;
  //Is user in database?
  User.find({ email: userEmail }, (err, user) => {
    if (!err) {
      //Compare password to database password
      bcrypt.compare(userPass, user.password, (err, result) => {
        console.log(user.pasword);
        console.log(userPass);
        //If user pass in database, check if verified & redirect to success
        if (userPass === user.password) {
          if (user.isVerified) {
            res.redirect("/success");
          } else {
            res.send(
              "You are not verified. Please check your email to access your account."
            );
          }
        } else {
          res.send("Incorrect password");
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It is probably an issue in your frontend and not your backend. You have to check what your frontend is sending the backend.

Comment: Delete the entry for this account in your mongodb, then start debugging